# How will I remove nulls from each columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

How will I remove nulls from each columns
This is the example

```
Column 1  Column 2 column 3  column 4 
a           1        null      null   
b           0        null      null   
c           1        null      null   
a           null      0        null   
b           null      1        null   
c           null      0        null   
a           null     null       1     
b           null     null       1     
c           null     null       0
```

I want it to look like this

```
Column 1  Column 2 column 3  column 4  
a            1        0         1      
b            0        1         1      
c            1        0         0
```

Is this possible?
You may see attached pictures for before and after image.

Comment: what about the possibility of having two same values in 1 column for two same rows?

Comment: What created those "inputs" in the first place? Is that the result of other, earlier computations? If so, then if you explain the entire problem (rather than just a part of it) we may be able to help you solve the entire problem much more simply than generating this intermediate result and then processing it further.

Answer (score 5):

You can use aggregation:

```
select col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3, max(col4) as col4
from t
group by col1;
```